# Application.cfc vs Application.cfm and also the need to extend Application.cfc

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, application.cfc

I'm moving away from ColdFusion 8 to ColdFusion 10.

Currently, on my Unix's root directory, I only have 1 Application.cfm and under this root directory I have about 10 sub directories (previous programmers did it this way and I'm experiencing a lot of weird things).

Now that I get the chance to redo this web application, I want to do it properly but the biggest problem with me is to properly understand how to work with Application.cfc in CF10.

Each of the sub directory represents a web application. For example, there is a web application for tracking graduate students, a web app. for tracking alumni, a web app. for formatting addresses, etc.

Users for these applications are from 10 different institutions. They all login to the application the same way (from the same interface) but then we separate them using `session.usergoup` & `session.username` to know who is who and who can see what type of things.

All Institutions share the same database, so currently only the datasource is set to application scope.

Unfortunately after reading many Application.cfc postings at this forum I got even more confused, so I hope you guys don't mind assisting me so that I can feel more comfortable working with Application.cfc in CF10.

My understanding is:

On my root dir I will create one main Application.cfc. My Main Application.cfc will only handle login/user authentication.

So under this root dir, I will have 1 Application.cfc, loginform.cfm and loginaction.cfm

In loginaction.cfm is where I set `session.usergroup` and `session.username` upon successful user authentication.

So in my main Application.cfc, I should set the following:

```
<cfset THIS.Name = "InstitutionMainApp" />
<cfset THIS.ApplicationTimeout = CreateTimeSpan(0,0,30,0) />
<cfset THIS.SessionManagement = true />
<cfset THIS.SetClientCookies = false />
```

under OnApplicationStart I'll do:

```
<cfset application.dsn = "MyDB">
```

and under OnSessionStart I'll do:

```
<cfset session.usergroup= "">
<cfset session.username= "">
```

Then on each of my sub-folder's Application.cfc I need to name it differently
For graduate tracking system I should have:

```
<cfset THIS.Name = "GraduateTrackingSystem" />
<cfset THIS.ApplicationTimeout = CreateTimeSpan(0,0,30,0) />
<cfset THIS.SessionManagement = true />
<cfset THIS.SetClientCookies = false />
```

under OnRequestStart, when I need to encrypt url variable (form example), I can set:

```
<cfset request.mySecretKey = application.mySecretKey />
<cfset request.algorithm = "AES" />
<cfset request.encoding = "hex" />
```

For alumni tracking system I should have:

```
<cfset THIS.Name = "AlumniTrackingSystem" />
<cfset THIS.ApplicationTimeout = CreateTimeSpan(0,0,30,0) />
<cfset THIS.SessionManagement = true />
<cfset THIS.SetClientCookies = false />
```

under OnRequestStart, when I need to encrypt url variable (form example), I can set:

```
<cfset request.mySecretKey = application.mySecretKey />
<cfset request.algorithm = "AES" />
<cfset request.encoding = "hex" />
```

For Address Formating app., I should set:

```
<cfset THIS.Name = "AddressFormattingSystem" />
<cfset THIS.ApplicationTimeout = CreateTimeSpan(0,0,30,0) />
<cfset THIS.SessionManagement = true />
<cfset THIS.SetClientCookies = false />
```

under OnRequestStart, when I need to encrypt url variable (form example), I can set:

```
<cfset request.mySecretKey = application.mySecretKey />
<cfset request.algorithm = "AES" />
<cfset request.encoding = "hex" />
```

Then since the `application.dsn`, `session.usergroup` and `session.username` are all set in
the Main Application.cfc under the root dir., I can freely use these scoped variables 
on each application sub-folder safely because each of sub-folder application.cfc is 
named differently this way I should not be concern with cross reference among usergroup 
and username?

Please let me know if my understanding on how to use Application.cfc is very much a 
mess.

Comment: Also, since you're rewriting this stack of applications, I'd look into using an MVC framework with a service layer to better organize and reuse code. ColdBox or FW/1 would be an excellent place to start.

Comment: I'm beginning to think you don't really need additional application.cfc's for the sub applications.

Answer (score 2):

That's a long question.

I think this is what you need: http://corfield.org/blog/index.cfm/do/blog.entry/entry/Extending_Your_Root_Applicationcfc

Once you have extended your application.cfc via some proxy to workaround the limitation of extending itself, you should be able to do almost anything your existing application.cfm was setup to do.

**update:** as iKnowKungFoo pointed out in the comment, once you have a different application name i.e. `this.name` you cannot share the vars in the `Application` scope since you're essentially forking a new application, you may try `Server` scope for those.  Logic can be shared via functions you have inherited, but pay attention to whether the vars are accessible in your application.

Comment: The wall you're going to hit quickly is that by extending Application.cfc in the other folders, they will ALL run as a SINGLE application. The values you set in the root Application.cfc will exist for all of the sub-applications. Also, there is no need for request.X = application.X, just reference application.X in your code. If you have session variables that are related to a specific sub-application, then re-create those variables into different session structs: session.graduateTrackingSystem, session.AlumniTrackingSystem, etc.

Comment: @iKnowKungFoo it has been a while but are you sure the child can't override `this.name` of the parent?

Comment: If you want to use the same application variables from the root, then you have to use the same application.name. If you extend the root Application.cfc and change this.name, then you're creating an entirely separate application scope, copying the same data from the root application. The same with session. If you change session.X in a sub-application, it wouldn't change the value of the root application's session.x. However, if you keep it all under one application name, then they all share session.x.